# Div Position in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know the Client div position

```
    var p = $('div#Client');
    var position = p.position();
    $('div#Client').fadeTo('slow',.6);
    $('div#Client').append('<div style="position: absolute;top:' + position.top + ';
    left:' + position.left + ';width: 100%;height:100%;z-index:2;opacity:0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50)"></div>');
```

The result is:

> Position.left = 0 and Top = 0

so the new Div in the Jquery code is on all the page

what I need is to put the new div on top of the `div#Client`

HTML code:

```
<div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px">
   <div class="Title">Sales</div>
      <div id="Sales" class="Content">
         Some infos for Sales person here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px">
   <div class="Title">Client</div>
      <div id="Client" class="Content">
         Some infos for the client here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

this is : http://jsfiddle.net/aaNUa/14/

Actually what's I'm trying to do is to block the Div Client but keep the Div Sales activated for editing. with this code all the page is blocked.

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle or plunkr with your code.

Comment: how about making a JSFiddle?

Comment: You don't need `'div#Client'`. Since the ID is unique, you can just use `'#Client'`. And if you use `opacity:0.4`, you might want to use `filter:alpha(opacity=40)` (instead of `50`)

Comment: Does this `$('div#Client').fadeTo('slow',.6);` mean that `#Client` has `display:none` before that? Because then you can't get the position ([see link](http://api.jquery.com/position/))

Comment: @RaviH: JSFiddle : added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use before() method in Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("div#Client").before('<div class="Title">Client</div>');
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aaNUa/

HTML Code :

```
<div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px">
   <div class="Title">Sales</div>
      <div id="Sales" class="Content">
         Some infos for Sales person here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px">

      <div id="Client" class="Content">
         Some infos for the client here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your CSS:

```
div#client{
  position:relative;
}
```

so that the inner DIV which is absolutely positioned will properly align with the parent div.

Comment: Hi Veera, I try it but in this case div#client is no longer Blocked THanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the content of function append()  in one line.